# Merge into is not inserting the expected rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, merge, oracle10g

```
MERGE
INTO             cars2 
USING            abc 
ON ( 
                                  cars2.vehicleid = abc.vehicleid) 
WHEN NOT matched THEN 
INSERT 
       ( 
              cars2.vehicleid, 
              cars2.brand, 
              cars2.model, 
              cars2.vehicle_type, 
              cars2.fuel_type, 
              cars2.transmission_type, 
              cars2.gearbox, 
              cars2.drive_type, 
              cars2.vehicle_number, 
              cars2.price 
       ) 
       >>VALUES 
       ( 
              abc.vehicleid, 
              abc.brand, 
              abc.model, 
              abc.vehicle_type, 
              abc.fuel_type, 
              abc.transmission_type, 
              abc.gearbox, 
              abc.drive_type, 
              abc.vehicle_number, 
              abc.price 
       ) 
WHERE  abc.vehicleid < 1000;
```

When I am executing the above it says 0 rows inserted.But actually it should insert two rows. Can any one please help me on this ?

```
select VEHICLEID from abc where vehicleid > 1000;
```

Output:-

```
VEHICLEID
9977
9978
```

Comment: In the query you are using `>` but in the merge you are using `<`. Which one is correct?

Comment: Two different filter predicates, two different result sets. So what's your problem?

Comment: select VEHICLEID from abc where vehicleid > 1000; Just for the your reference i have shown that i have two entries in abc table with Vehicle ID greater than 1000. I am using "WHEN NOT MATCHED" in MERGE Statement right, so i used "where abc.vehicleid < 1000;" in MERGE Statement. My doubt is why is it not inserting those 2 rows. Also What  "WHEN NOT MATCHED" actually does ?

Comment: Adding a comment, i am new to Oracle. i want to know what "WHEN NOT MATCHED" actually means ? because when i use "where abc.vehicleid **>** 1000;" in MERGE Statement its inserting the two rows correctly/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you need a subtle modification. Your where clause is in the wrong place.

```
MERGE
INTO cars2 
USING (
   select * from abc WHERE  abc.vehicleid < 1000) abc
ON (cars2.vehicleid = abc.vehicleid) 
WHEN NOT matched THEN 
INSERT 
       ( 
              cars2.vehicleid, 
              cars2.brand, 
              cars2.model, 
              cars2.vehicle_type, 
              cars2.fuel_type, 
              cars2.transmission_type, 
              cars2.gearbox, 
              cars2.drive_type, 
              cars2.vehicle_number, 
              cars2.price 
       ) 
       >>VALUES 
       ( 
              abc.vehicleid, 
              abc.brand, 
              abc.model, 
              abc.vehicle_type, 
              abc.fuel_type, 
              abc.transmission_type, 
              abc.gearbox, 
              abc.drive_type, 
              abc.vehicle_number, 
              abc.price 
       )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so what is the use of giving where clause after insert statement ?. Please clarify me.

Comment: I think that WHERE clause was applying weirdly to the insert statement itself and was never true... so it never inserted anything. You could probably see that in the execution plan.